# how to calculate inter-rater agreement of nominal data with multiple categories in r

Tags: r, reliability, agreement-statistics

[coder1 results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0HnH.png)

[coder2 results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aknWZ.png)

Hi, what method should I use to calculate inter-coder reliability between these 
two data in r?
The row stands for the cases, and the a1~ a23/A1~A23 stands for the categories. The results consists of 0(no) or 1(yes). If the case includes any of the categories, "1" is given. 
Since the cases can be multi-categorical, normal Kripphendore's alpha doesn't seem to work. :(

Comment: By the way, whoever downvoted it might be helpful, in general, if you explained why when you do so.

Comment: You need to do a literature search to find out how others have handled this problem.  I'm sure others have encountered this same situation.

Comment: You need to specify first how you define agreement between your two 23 valued vectors.

Comment: Restoring my comment from SO, which was deleted without explanation: It seems this question may be better suited for Cross Validated, where you can find posts like this: stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inter-rater You might also want to look into the package irr (which I have no experience with) cran.r-project.org/package=irr If you get to working with some code and run into some specific problem with your R code then come back here with a question for that (and be sure to have a look at stackoverflow.com/help/mcve about posting reproducible examples.) I hope that helps, good luck!

Comment: I actually solved this problem by combining the categories, and rating the cases by the number of categories they fall into. It's not a good solution but, anyways! Thank you for your kind comments :)